# How to center a php include?

Tags: php, include, center

here is a portion of the php code.  What I want to do is center the results of "include'config.php' " on the web page.

---

```
function draw_calendar($month, $year) {


     include 'config.php';

/* draw table */
$calendar = '<table align="center"; cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

/* table headings */
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps add a simple echo which outputs some css style, or add that style directly in your template

```
<?php echo"<div style='text-align:center'>";  include 'config.php'; echo "</div>";  ?>
```